# Apache .htaccess mod_rewrite: use of [NC]

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

I see tons of `.htaccess` examples containing the `[NC]` flag (NoCase = case-insensitive)

For example the famous h5bp page uses the `[NC]` flag a lot:
https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/dist/.htaccess

Nearly every example puts the `[NC]` flag at the end of the `RewriteCond` directive.
But the [Official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc) clearly states it is used only for the `RewriteRule` directive.

Are 99% of the examples wrong ?
Is the official documentation wrong or incomplete ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But the Official documentation clearly states it is used only for the RewriteRule directive.

The docs don't say that it can *only* be used on the `RewriteRule` directive. The page you link to (which incidentally is specifically about the `RewriteRule` flags) simply states:

> Use of the [NC] flag causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a case-insensitive manner.

The [docs for the `RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) include a section on the flags that can be used with this directive. And these include `NC`, `OR` and `NV`. The `NC` flag is common to both directives.

If you did use an invalid flag on the `RewriteCond` directive you'll get a 500 Internal Server error. And if you examine the server's error log you should see something about "invalid flags".

However, (bit of an aside), the `NC` flag is generally used too much. People often include it by default, when it really isn't necessary (or worse, will actually cause problems).

---

#### A closer look

I'm not sure if the linked document has been updated in the last few years, but there are just 3 cases of the `NC` flag being used with the `RewriteCond` directive. The first 2 are certainly justified, the 3rd is debatable  IMO.

> ```
> #376   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
> ```

When resolving the hostname (value of the `Host` header) it should always be compared case-insensitively (according to the HTTP spec). All mainstream browsers lowercase the `Host` header when making the request. However, other user-agents (and bots) may not and mod_rewrite will naturally compare this case-sensitively by default. That doesn't necessarily mean you should always use the `NC` flag as it does depend on exactly what it is you are doing.

However, the `NC` flag is justified here since the goal of this rule is to remove the `www` subdomain, whether that is `www`, `wWw` or `WWW`. Without the `NC` flag, a (malicious) user-agent could send `WWW.EXAMPLE.COM` and circumvent the canonical redirect to the domain apex.

> ```
> #408   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
> ```

Note that this is a *negated* regex (denoted by the `!` prefix). The goal of this rule is to redirect from the domain apex to the `www` subdomain. The `NC` flag is justified here, since you want to prevent the redirect when the `Host` header starts with `www` or `WWW` etc. Otherwise you could potentially get a malformed redirect like `www.WWW.example.com`.

> ```
> #564   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!(^|/)\.well-known/([^./]+./?)+$" [NC]
> ```

The use of the `NC` flag here is debatable IMO. The goal of this rule block is to block access to dot-files and directories, except the `.well-known` directory. At best it's probably superfluous, however, it does contradict similar conditions used earlier in the file (lines #345-7) that do not use the `NC` flag.

The `.well-known` directory *should* always be lowercase. So, the `NC` flag *should* be superfluous. However, by including the `NC` flag here we end up *allowing* (not blocking) requests of the form `.WELL-KNOWN` - which are likely to fail anyway given that we are probably on Linux, which is case-sensitive.

Comment: you know a lot about htaccess directives, know any places for learning the rewrite syntax? I find httpd.apache.org annoying to use, its all scattered and doesn't show good examples with complex rewrites.

Comment: @SimonHayter Well, I don't really have any magic resources for learning this stuff unfortunately. A lot of trial & error, testing and questioning everything. Although the Apache docs are perhaps too concise in many areas, with few examples, I do find them an invaluable reference. Complex rewrites often involve complex regex, which the Apache docs don't cover at all. http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is my goto resource for regex, although navigation can be a bit tricky as well. http://www.askapache.com/ is a great resource with loads of code snippets and raw examples but little explanation.